# JPA / Hibernate occasionally running completely wrong SQL for relationship data

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**This one has got me lost for ideas.**

So I have a class that is a data model class Called **ServiceForm** which has about 15 joins to related data tables, a combination of one-to-many and one-to-one joins.

I call the repository (ServiceFormRepository) to retrieve a single ServiceForm record. Hibernate then handles loading all of the related data for this class.

98% of the time this is working fine and I see the hibernate logs running a query for the ServiceForm and then a query for each of the related tables (Not the most efficient way I know).

However occasionally it will start running the wrong queries for the related data retrieval. The logs will show that it will repeatedly run for example the 3rd related data query instead of running the 4th, 5th, 6th query.

This will generally then continue to happen until I restart the server. Retrying the same record after restarting the server will then work perfectly again.

[Example of correct logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h06Z.png) - You can see a different query on each line as it is retrieving the different related data.

[Example of bad logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zMI4.png) - Now you can see that it keeps running the 3rd query multiple times, it doesn't change to the SQL for the other relationships.

When this happens it fails to retrieve the data for some of the relationships.

Restarting the spring-boot server is the only solution I've found to get things working consistently again.
Have seen this go a full week without happening and then happen multiple times in the one day.

- **This is running on a Spring-boot server.**
- **Database is Azure SQL Server**
- **Happens on production server plus has happened on my local machine so not limited to one machine.**
- **No exceptions are thrown.**

**Snippet of code showing call to retrieve ServiceForm record.**

```
@Autowired
ServiceFormService serviceFormService;
...
...
// Line below is inside a method where call is made to the ServiceFormService to retrieve the data.
ServiceForm serviceForm = serviceFormService.getServiceFormBySubmissionId(formSubmission.getSubmissionId());
```

**Snipped of code in the ServiceFormService class where repository is called.**

```
@Service
public class ServiceFormService {

    @Autowired
    ServiceFormRepository serviceFormRepo;

    public ServiceForm getServiceFormBySubmissionId(String submissionId) {

        return serviceFormRepo.getBySubmissionId(submissionId);
    }

}
```

**Snippet of code showing joins in ServiceForm class.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ServiceForm")
public class ServiceForm implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private Integer id;

   // Needs unique property when joining tables with non-PK associations otherwise hibernate throws exception cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable.
   @Column(name = "submissionId", nullable = true, unique = true)
   private String submissionId;

...
...


   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private CustomerDetails customerDetails;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private Jsea jsea;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId")
   })
   private List<InverterInspection> inverterInspections = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private Set<SwitchBoard> switchBoards = new LinkedHashSet<>();

...
...

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private CompletionNotes completionNotes;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "submissionId", referencedColumnName = "submissionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private Compliance compliance;

}
```

I have not been able to narrow this down to being a code issue or some kind of server problem, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Have started to wonder if it might be a database connection related issue.

Comment: Looks like this is just what is necessary to fulfill the `EAGER` fetching of the `compliance` relationship, but it's really hard to tell without actually debugging into the specific case.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov - I don't believe that to be the case. The Compliance relationship is a 1-to-1 relationship and with this data there should never be a need for it to run more than one query for this relationship. Also when this problem occurs where it repeats the compliance SQL, if I restart the server and try to retrieve the exact same record again it does not run the compliance SQL multiple times, just once. The problem does not occur frequently enough to debug unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know what the behaviour of hibernate is if there are issues with the database connection? Could it possibly be retrying to run a query multiple times due to connection issues or would an exception be thrown straight away without a retry attempt?

Comment: I don't know how your model looks like. You could have more assocations referring to `compliance`. Anyway, you'd have to debug this to understand what is happening. You can turn on debug logging to see what is going on. There is no retrying in Hibernate. You will receive the exception wrapped in a HibernateException in your application if something goes wrong on the JDBC level.